# How does a Stream Thread in Kafka Streams switch between its task?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have been looking at understanding how in Kafka stream, a Stream Thread switch between the execution of the Tasks it is assigned with, but could not find the answer online.

Thread pool are well understood in Java, we know we should not block in our code, as this can quickly lead to thread starvation. In other words, a task will execute until it finishes, then the thread takes anything else that has been submitted to the thread pool.

Hence in the same spirit, I am wondering given that task read data that continuously come through their input partitions, which technically never ends, how does a Stream thread, switch between task?

This information can be helpful in deciding how many task we are prepared to pack per stream thread, depending on what we know about our workload.

Comment: Hi there Matt. Please note that "trough" is not the spelling you want - you want "through". A trough is a feeding container for animals. This has been fixed many times in your post already (13 more to fix).

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka `StreamThread` is *not* analogous to a threadpool. A StreamThread processes one record at a time, from the first Task in the topology down through the completion of the Topology for that one Record.

Once the Record has been processed, a new input Record is fetched from the Input Topics.

Only one StreamThread may process records from any given partition; however, one StreamThread may process multiple partitions. Therefore it is useless to have more StreamThread's than input partitions.

I would recommend over-allocating the number of partitions so that you can increase the number of stream threads as you scale up.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Multiple task can be assign to a stream thread, the question is how do the stream thread switch between its task. After processing one record, 2, 3, is it random, dynamic, is there any logic at all lol 

Comment: Of course I know it is not a thread pool, to which you submit task. As a matter of fact, the framework assigned the task « once and for all ». Then the thread execute its task, but obviously to switch between them it must follow some logic

Comment: A "Task" is just a partition from which input records come from. The Stream Thread takes the earliest available record and processes it. The records are processed one at a time.

Comment: Thanks. Still not answering the question tho